# Role of alcoholic potassium hydroxide in an E2 reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination

> Which of the following compound will give least substituted alkene as major product with alcoholic $\ce{KOH}$.
>
> The options are:
>
> 1.[image]
> 2.
> [image]
>
> 3.[image]
> 4.
> [image]

I am confused between options 1 and 3. Both seem to give more substituted alkene as the major product. Does alcoholic $\ce{KOH}$ always mean it is an E2 elimination?

What is the mechanism here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110893/discussion-on-question-by-shubham-sagar-role-of-alcoholic-potassium-hydroxide-in).

Answer (score 2):

Haloalkanes react with alc. $\ce{KOH}$ mainly via $E_2$ mechanism. But, in some cases, where $\beta-\ce{H}$ isn't present, it proceeds via $E_1$, as in case of $(4)$ one. Let's analyze each option,

## Option $(1)$:

Firstly, the $\ce{-Cl}$ departs, and then the base picks up a $\beta-\ce{H}$ from the terminal methyl group (i.e., $\ce{C-5}$), resulting in **mono-** substituted alkene (Hofmann product as major). **Steric factors** are significant in selectivity of $\beta-\ce{H}$. Therefore, Zaitsev product will be formed in *very minor* concentrations, bcoz $\ce{-C(CH3)2Ph}$ is more bulkier substituent than $\ce{^tBu}$.

## Option $(3)$:

This one is similar to $(1)$ case, except for the fact that due to less steric hindrance, it will give **di-** substituted alkene (Zaitsev product).

**Option $(2)$:** It's clear that this molecule will form a **tri-** substituted alkene.

**Option $(4)$:** As hinted above, it will proceed through $E_1$, resulting in a **tri-** substituted alkene.

---

Different levels of substitution are shown below, (source: [www.chemistrysteps.com](https://www.chemistrysteps.com/zaitsevs-rule-regioselectivity-of-e2-elimination-reactions/))

[image: substitution-in-alkene]

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135700/which-will-be-major-and-minor-alkene-formed-if-e1-reaction-occurs-on-2-chloro-2